# Swift alert action handler not working specific case

Tags: ios, swift, alert, handler

I'm creating an app that displays users comments. User enters a comment and then clicks submit button and then an alert action view should occur. I'm trying to direct a user to my fourthviewcontroller when the ok button in the alert view is clicked. Here is my code, it should work fine.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Succesful", message: "Successfully added!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
let uivc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)
 }))
 self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

However, I get this error when I click on the OK button.

'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

FourthViewController is created based on the user's selections on the past three viewcontrollers. There is a unique fourthviewcontroller based on the combination of the tableview cells clicked in the previous view controllers. I believe the problem arises because when I direct the user to FourthViewController, the app does not know what the FourthViewController contains as there were no tableview cells clicked before. When I change the direction of the VC from FourthViewController to FirstViewController everything works amazingly.

Is it possible to fix this issue?  I'd appreciate any help! Thank you very much and have a good day!

Comment: Can you explain better your question? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Tried to explain more clearly now. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the FourthViewController has some variables which depend on the previous ViewControllers. In that case just initialise these variables setting their value: uivc.varName = value

You may also perform a segue instead of instantiating the view controller and you can set the values of the nextViewController in the prepare function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line form  action completion

```
  let uivc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController")
  self.navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)
```

and make a function as below

```
 func navigate(){

 let uivc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController")
  self.navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)

   }
```

now add following in action completion

```
 self.navigate()
```

like below

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Succesful", message: "Successfully added!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
 self.navigate() 
  }))
 self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: @Bobbydickson that means problem in your code not in the above posted code its anywhere else, i am sure its not over the code you posted in question, try to figure it out and post exact code where you are getting this problem